# Array.push() and console.log() gives different variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to modify this

```
var array = [{"host": ["example.com", "www.example.com"], "from": "test1", "to": "test2"},
 {"host": ["example.net", "www.example.net"], "from": "test3", "to": "test4"}];
```

into this on Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m

```
[{"host": "example.com", "from": "test1", "to": "test2"},
 {"host": "www.example.com", "from": "test1", "to": "test2"},
 {"host": "example.net", "from": "test3", "to": "test4"},
 {"host": "www.example.net", "from": "test3", "to": "test4"}];
```

i used code

```
array.forEach(function(rule){
     rule.host.forEach(function(host){
         var tmp = rule;
         tmp.host = host;
         result.push(tmp);
     });
 });
```

but it gives

```
[{"host": "www.example.com", "from": "test1", "to": "test2"},
 {"host": "www.example.com", "from": "test1", "to": "test2"},
 {"host": "www.example.net", "from": "test3", "to": "test4"},
 {"host": "www.example.net", "from": "test3", "to": "test4"}];
```

When I replace `array.push` with `console.log()` it log right variables. It can not be async issue with `array.push()`, because I tried old `array.length` way to add to array - no changes. May be I use `foreach` wrong - there are lot of `Array.prototype` methods - I can't get right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays and Objects in Javascript are passed and assigned by reference, not by value. `var tmp = rule` is merely making a second pointer to the original rule, then you are overwriting the data and printing each entry twice. To achieve the desired effect, you must clone *all* of the data in the entries into new entries.

```
array.forEach(function(rule){
    rule.host.forEach(function(host){
        result.push({
            host: host,
            from: rule.from,
            to: rule.to
        });
    });
});
```